# Antiderivative of discontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am having confusion regarding anti-derivative of a function.

$$f(x)  =
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-\frac{x^2}{2} + 4 & x \le 0  \\
\phantom{-} \frac{x^2}{2} + 2 & x > 0
\end{array} \right.
$$

Consider the domain $[-1, 2]$.
Clearly the function is Riemann integrable as it is discontinuous at finite number of point. However is there a function $g(x)$ such that $g'(x) = f(x) \forall x \in [-1,2] $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function, because by Darboux's theorem (cf. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))), every derivative has to fulfill the intermediate value theorem, but $f$ does not.

Comment: Thanks! However,I am unable to apply the Darboux's theorem in the question. How does the given f(x) fail this test ? Please elaborate.

Comment: Take $\epsilon > 0$ small enough. Then $f|_{[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon]}$ assumes values $>3$ (actually arbitrary close to $4$, namely "just left of the origin") and values $<3$ (actually arbitrary close to $2$, namely "just right of the origin"), but if $\epsilon$ is small enough, $f$ does NOT assume the value $3$ itself on $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$.

Answer (score 4):

No. The best you can do is a function $g$ that is *continuous* everywhere, and differentiable with $g'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ except at $x=0$. Since $g'(x)$ has different one sided limits at $x=0$, $g$ cannot be differentiable there.

But this $g$ is a sufficiently good antiderivative for computing definite integrals of $f$, as you can see by splitting the integral in two parts: $\int_a^b=\int_a^0+\int_+^b$ if $a<0<b$.

Comment: I just happened by and noticed a misprint: The lower limit in the last integral should of course be $0$, not $+$. I don't want to bump the question to the front page, so I am just leaving this note instead.